# How to auto-update audio slider jquery ui

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, audio, slider

I'm looking for help because I am currently stuck on a script. 
Let me explain: I have on a page an html5 audio player, as well as a slider acting on the value "id".audio, made ​​using the jquery ui library..

When we act on the slider, the audio value is automatically changed, and also the player's value, but when we act on the slider of the player, that realized with jquery (the slider) does not change unless you change the value before you load the script ... 
In summary I would like to know how to make the slider to update itself automatically, depending on the html5 audio player.

Here is the script:

```
    $(function() {

        //Store frequently elements in variables
        var slider  = $('#slider'),
            tooltip = $('.tooltip');

        //Hide the Tooltip at first
        tooltip.hide();

        //Call the Slider
        $(window).load(function(){
        slider.slider({
            //Config
            range: "min",
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            animate: true,
            value: audio1.volume,
            step: 0.01,             
            start: function(event,ui) {
                tooltip.fadeIn('fast');
            },

            //Slider Event
            slide: function(e, ui) { //When the slider is sliding

                var value  = slider.slider('value'),
                    volume = $('.volume');
                audio1.volume = ui.value;
                if(value <= 0.05) { 
                    volume.css('background-position', '0 0');
                } 
                else if (value <= 0.25) {
                    volume.css('background-position', '0 -25px');
                } 
                else if (value <= 0.75) {
                    volume.css('background-position', '0 -50px');
                } 
                else {
                    volume.css('background-position', '0 -75px');
                };

            },

            stop: function(event,ui) {
                tooltip.fadeOut('fast');
            },
        });

    });
    });
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english (not my native language), 
Aurélien

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to bind the values together in both directions, here's a simple example based on a video player I've been working on.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/w9W7d/1/)**

```
$(function () {
    var seeksliding;
    var createSeek = function () {
        if ($('#audio').prop('readyState')) { 

            var audio_duration = $('#audio').prop('duration'); 

            $('#seekSlider').slider({
                value: 0,
                step: 0.01,
                orientation: "horizontal",
                range: "min",
                max: audio_duration, 
                animate: 200,
                slide: function () {
                    seeksliding = true;
                },
                stop: function (e, ui) {
                    seeksliding = false;
                    $('#audio').prop("currentTime", ui.value);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    createSeek();

    var seekUpdate = function () {
        var currenttime = $('#audio').prop('currentTime');
        if (!seeksliding) $('#seekSlider').slider('value', currenttime);
    };

    $('#audio').bind('timeupdate', seekUpdate);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! :)
But, the problem is that they are already linked by the "audio.volume" value : the default html5 player auto-refresh itself, contrary to the custom who, once loaded, doesn't listen to the value anymore : it is where i need help :/